# jupyter: No such kernel named python3

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, jupyter

I want to run jupyter in pycharm, but encountered error: No such kernel named python3.

I only installed Anaconda(Python3 64bit version) and use this as the pycharm project interpreter.

[image]

......

[image]

Jupyter kernelspec list shows following:
[image]

Appreciate any helps!!

Comment: the `get_kernel_spec` function is returning a map like so for me:
`Python [Root]: /Users/<username>/anaconda/bin/python`

There's no 'python3' entry in the map, indeed.

Comment: Looks like a bug in PyCharm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20023

Comment: It has been fixed by PyCharm.

Comment: In an unreleased version? Because the bug is still there for me in the latest Release Candidate of the PyCharm CE from July 15, 2016.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We've released versions of `nb_conda`, `nb_conda_kernels` and `nb_anacondacloud` through the official Anaconda conda repos that should resolve the issues you are seeing!

`shell
conda update nb_conda nb_conda_kernels nb_anacondacloud`

As-installed kernel names that are eligible for being `default` (e.g. `python2`, `python3`, `ir`, etc.) will be maintained unmodified, so they should always appear there.

The downside is as many as three options for the current env, i.e. if you are in root, you will see *Python 2* and *Python [root]* and *Python [default]*, you can now reproducibly capture which environment your kernel should run against.

meta: https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/anaconda-nb-extensions/issues/166

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.
I use jupyter through Anaconda, as you do.
It appears that PyCharm try to run an engine named by default "python3" but it is named "Python[Root]" in anaconda default installation.

After a few debugging, the issue seems to be:

- In PyCharm which uses NATIVE_KERNEL_NAME by default in place of default conda kernel named "Python [Root]"
- Or in conda CondaKernelSpecManager.find_kernel_specs methods which removes default native kernel names apparently with no good reason and anyway, in a bad way

For the short answer, I've **worked around** by editing manually

> anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nb_conda_kernels/manager.py

This is probably not the best option, but for the moment it works

```
def find_kernel_specs(self):
    """Returns a dict mapping kernel names to resource directories.

    The update process also add the resource dir for the conda
    environments.
    """

    kspecs = super(CondaKernelSpecManager, self).find_kernel_specs()

    # COMMENT THIS
    # remove native kernels because it is provided by the env name
    # if "python3" in kspecs:
    #     kspecs.pop("python3")
    # elif "python2" in kspecs:
    #     kspecs.pop("python2")
    # elif "R" in kspecs
```

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/936

Comment: More info on this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jupyter/qE6fCyXe6fs/GdYLqI9dAQAJ

Answer (score 3):

This solved issue for me:

```
 conda install nb_conda_kernels
```